# JavaScript + MAC OS + правая кнопка мыши в текстовом поле

Tags: javascript, mac

Если вы счастливый обладатель mac, вы возможно замечали, что когда вы делаете клик правой клавишей мыши в текстовом поле на каком нибудь слове, то это слово автоматически выделяется (http://prnt.sc/ch0fd3). Я так понимаю что это фишка чисто мака, на винде таких приколов нет. Нужно сделать так чтоб при клике правой кнопкой мыши текст не выделялся и по возможности курсор (тот что в тексте) оставался на своем месте

У меня чистая HTML страница на которой есть textarea и вот такой js код

```
document.getElementById("textarea").onmousedown = function(event){
    if ( event.button == 2 ){
        event.preventDefault();
        // немного моего кода
    }
}
```

Что я пробовал писать:

- event.preventDefault(); - не дает нужного мне результата
- event.target.selectionStart = event.target.selectionEnd; пробовал использовать selection но в момент клика еще ничего не выделено
- если вариант selection скомбинировать с setTimeout тогда работает но появляется не нужное мерцание

Comment: Если это системная фишка, то JS не в силах помочь, только обходные костыли городить.

Comment: Мака под рукой нет. Но вы попробуйте подход с `event.target.selectionStart = event.target.selectionEnd` сделать на событие *onmouseup*.

Comment: onmouseup - как вариант, можно использовать но пока мы держим зажатую клавишу мыши (после down перед up) текст будет выделен, и получается мерцание текста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать средствами CSS отключить выделение полностью, но это не позволит Вам поставить курсор в текст:

```
body{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805684/javascript-disable-text-select)

Если же нужно конкретно JS и ставить курсор, то посмотрите в сторону `oncontextmenu`, так как это евент именно для правой кнопки мыши.